# How to prevent/disable an <a href> based on geoip data

Tags: php, geoip

I'm an absolute beginner when it comes to php and js and have been pulling my hair out trying to find a workable solution to the following requirement.

I have a Joomla subscription extension with a "subscribe" button using an a href tag.

What I'd like to achieve is, based on geoip location, visitors browsing from outside the UK are denied access to the button click action, but given a message explaining why.

So far all I'm able to achieve is a disabled button, which is still clickable...

The little-bit I've been able to achieve so far is below. Really hoping someone can assist me.

```
<?php
// Added Geo IP Location Tracking
$user_ip = getenv('REMOTE_ADDR');
// http://www.geoplugin.net/php.gp?ip=$user_ip
$geo = unserialize(file_get_contents("http://www.geoplugin.net/php.gp?ip=$user_ip"));
$city = $geo["geoplugin_city"];
$region = $geo["geoplugin_regionName"];
$country = $geo["geoplugin_countryName"];
$countryCode = $geo["geoplugin_countryCode"];
}
?>


<?php
if ($countryCode == 'CH') {


echo "Unfortunately China is not covered by our service!"."<br>";           
}
?>

<p><a class="btn btn-large btn-primary" <?php if ($countryCode == 'CH'){ ?> disabled <?php   } ?> href="<?php echo JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_axisubs&view=subscribe&plan='.$item->slug); ?>">
<i class="icon-ok"></i>

<?php if ( $item->hasTrial() ) : ?>
<?php echo JText::_('COM_AXISUBS_START_TRIAL'); ?>
<?php else: ?>
<?php echo JText::_('COM_AXISUBS_SUBSCRIBE_NOW'); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant set links to "disabled" this works only for form elements like  input, textfield, button etc.

What you can do is to add some javascript to prevent the default action of the link :

```
<a class="btn btn-large btn-primary" <?= ($countryCode != 'CH')?'onclick="return false;"':'' ?> href="<?php echo JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_axisubs&view=subscribe&plan='.$item->slug); ?>">
```

By using this method, you can also add a message in an alert box for example when the user is not in the required country :

```
<a class="btn btn-large btn-primary" <?= ($countryCode != 'CH')?'onclick="alert(\'you are not in CH\');return false;"':'' ?> href="<?php echo JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_axisubs&view=subscribe&plan='.$item->slug); ?>">
```

---

if you have to block many country codes, you can do this :

```
<a class="..." <?= (in_array($countryCode, ['CH', 'FR', 'UK', 'DE']))?'onclick="alert(\'you are not in an allowed country\');return false;"':'' ?> href="...">
```

Comment: This is brilliant! How could I block every country except the UK and then display the same message. Thanks Crozet

Comment: thanks for this suggestion. The alert box is helpful and actually better than hiding the actual button. Could someone just confirm if I'd have to add each $countryCode to block them one at a time?

Comment: if you have many countries to block, it would be better to replace `$countryCode == 'CH'` by a function `isBlocked()` which would return true or false or by `in_array($countryCode, $blockedCountryCodes)` where $countryCode is `['CH', 'UK', 'DE']` (the list of blocked country codes) see my edit

Comment: Thank you, thank you Crozet!! You have made my week. I cannot tell you how long I have worked and banged my head against the desk with trying to get this solved. You sir and everyone else that offered their assistance and suggestions are absolute gentlemen for passing on your knowledge. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You should not include your link at all to prevent abuse to your service.

`$link = $countryCode == 'CH' ? 
    'href="#" onclick="return false;" disabled' :
    'href="index.php?option=com_axisubs&view=subscribe&plan='.$item->slug.'"';`

and then output your link tag

`<a class="btn btn-large btn-primary" <?php echo $link ?>>`

This way link does not exist on your page and dummy link is not clickable.

Comment: Thanks Starast. I totally agree with your suggestion to hide the link and will try your suggestion. Many thanks!